# DNA barcoding, querry regarding tree based (cluster) methods for species identification

Tags: phylogenetics

I am working on success rate of DNA barcoding in identification of species using distance and tree based methods.

Regarding distance based method, I have used Adhoc and species identifier and confirmed species identification using best closest match criteria (BCM).

Please suggest program/software/method for tree based identification (using NJ, parsimony, bayes), exhibiting clustering (number of clusters formed for particular species) that will suggest singleton (=Ambigious) species.

(For more details: Attached image)
(Please Note: It is not possible to do it manually as iam having >4000 specimens)

Answers detailing methods or softwares appereciated! Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Are you searching for something like this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_phylogenetics_software

this post is some what off topic.

Comment: @Devashish Das, thank you for your reply, to make it more clear, ive attached image. Pls have a look, keep posting.

Comment: You can try PHYLIP and ClustalW. You can run them from commandline and this can be automated.